# Keep Uploaded Files in Sync Across Multiple Servers - PHP Linux

Tags: php, file, synchronization

I have a website right now that is currently utilizing 2 servers, a application server and a database server, however the load on the application server is increasing so we are going to add a second application server.

The problem I have is that the website has users upload files to the server. How do I get the uploaded files on both of the servers?

I do not want to store images directly in a database as our application is database intensive already.

Is there a way to sync the servers across each other or is there something else I can do?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

EDIT: I am adding the following links for people that helped me understand this question more:

[Synchronize Files on Multiple Servers](https://serverfault.com/questions/312306/synchronize-files-on-multiple-servers-rsync)
and
[Keep Uploaded Files in Sync Across Multiple Servers - LAMP](https://serverfault.com/questions/405873/keep-uploaded-files-in-sync-across-multiple-servers-lamp/405876#405876)

**For all Reading this post NFS seems to be the better of the 2.**

**NFS will keep files in sync but you could also use [ftp to upload](http://codestips.com/php-ftp-upload-tutorial/) the files across all servers as well but NFS looks like the way to go.**

Comment: I'm not flagging the post as I'm not sure of it, but maybe you could have a better luck on http://serverfault.com. I think that fits better, although a 'programming' solution could be possible.

Comment: I will ask there as well and if I get a answer I will post here for those who need it

Comment: Here is the link to the [serverfault](http://serverfault.com/questions/405873/keep-uploaded-files-in-sync-across-multiple-servers-lamp/405892#405892) question. They have some decent answer there as well

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/730528/synchronizing-files-across-multiple-servers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I got this answer from server fault:

*The most appropriate course of action in a situation like this is to break the file share into a separate service of its own. Don't duplicate files if you have a network that can let the files be "everywhere (almost) at once." You can do this through NFS/CIFS or through a proper storage protocol like iSCSI. Mount as local storage in the appropriate directory. Depending on the performance of your network and your storage needs, this could add a couple of undetectable milliseconds to page load time.*

So using NFS to share server files would work OR

as stated by @kgb you could specify one single server to hold all uploaded files and have other servers pull from that (just make sure you run a cron or something to back up the file)

Comment: This is, indeed, the best answer. I think NFS is the right solution. You can use crontab but in that way you will always have some time where the file are stored only in one server. With NFS it will work perfectly. You should mark your own answer as accepted here on SO, too, as long as it is the one that best fits your problem and other people will find it easily and will not use a crontab/rsync approach that is, in my opinion, wrong and redundant.

Answer (score 5):

This is a question for serverfault.
Anyway I think you should definitely consider getting in the "cloud". 
Syncing uploads from one server to another is simply unreliable - you have no idea what kind of errors you can get and why you can get them. Also the syncing process will load both servers. For me the proper solution is going in the cloud.

Should you chose the syncing method you have a couple of solutions:

1. Use `rsync` to sync the files you need between the servers.
2. Use `crontab` to sync the files every X minutes/hours/days.
3. Copy the files upon some event (user login etc)

Answer (score 2):

Most sites solve this problem by using a 3rd party designated file server like [Amazon S3](http://aws.amazon.com/s3/) for the user uploads.

Answer (score 2):

Another answer could be to use a piece of software called BTSync, it is very easy to install and use and could allow you to easily keep files in sync accross as many servers as you need to. It takes only 3 terminal commands to install and is very efficient.

[Take a look here](http://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=btsync%20ubuntu&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&sqi=2&ved=0CC0QFjAA&url=https://askubuntu.com/questions/284683/how-to-run-bittorrent-sync&ei=cTddUrrzJITLhAfS94HIAg&usg=AFQjCNFUqnfljaZEiPqxb-QlQNQdtIMJNg&sig2=MHkr1aLaPZp71k4SxIgl5A&bvm=bv.53899372,d.ZG4)

---

[and here](http://www.ruchirablog.com/install-configure-bittorrent-sync-server/)

Answer (score 1):

You can use db server for storage... Not in the db i mean, have a web server running there too.  It is not going to increase cpu load much, but is going to require a better channel.

Answer (score 1):

you could do it with rsync.. people have suggested using nfs.. but that way you create one point of failure... if the nfs server goes down.. both your servers are screwed... correct me if im wrong